# Animation Queue with transitionend

Tags: javascript, css

I have selected 4 DOM elements and am looking to animate one after the other using the `transitionend` event. Eventually I would like the `x` and `y` values of `translate3d()` to be dynamic, hence the reason this is being done in JS and not just using something like CSS @keyframe animations.

I currently have this working code, but feel like there could be a better way. Any pointers would be great. Thanks!

```js
var formComponents = document.querySelectorAll('.form-component');
formComponents[0].style.transitionDelay = '2s';
formComponents[0].style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d(550px, -250px, 0)';
formComponents[0].addEventListener('transitionend', function(e) {
  formComponents[1].style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d(315px, -250px, 0)';
  formComponents[1].addEventListener('transitionend', function(e) {
    formComponents[2].style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d(150px, -250px, 0)';
    formComponents[2].addEventListener('transitionend', function(e) {
      formComponents[3].style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d(-125px, -250px, 0)';
    }, false);
  }, false);
}, false);
```

```html
<div class="form-component"></div>
<div class="form-component"></div>
<div class="form-component"></div>
<div class="form-component"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could accomplish what you want with a `.reduce()` function that chains the `transitionend` events together.  In my example, I just toggle a class, but you could instead set an explicit transform on the element instead calculating the positioning you want using the `index` parameter of the `.reduce()`.  Consider the following:

```js
const transformer = document.getElementById("transformer"),
  targets = document.getElementsByClassName("changable");

const firstEl = targets[0];

if (firstEl) {
  Array.from(targets).slice(1).reduce((prev, el) => {
    prev.addEventListener("transitionend", e => {
      el.classList.toggle("change");
    });
    return el;
  }, firstEl);

  transformer.addEventListener("click", e => {
    targets[0].classList.toggle("change");
  });
}
```

```css
.changable {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: transform 200ms ease;
}

.change {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<p><span class="changable">Lorem Ipsum</span> <span class="changable">dolumn deloris</span> <span class="changable">dolumn deloris</span> <span class="changable">dolumn deloris</span> <span class="changable">dolumn deloris</span> <span class="changable">dolumn deloris</span>  <span class="changable">dolumn deloris</span> <span class="changable">dolumn deloris</span> <span class="changable">dolumn deloris</span> <span class="changable">dolumn deloris</span></p>
<button id="transformer" type="button">Transform</button>
```

Here is an example that keys off of the index of the array to scale the current element depending on its position in the array of all elements to be transformed:

```js
const transformer = document.getElementById("transformer"),
  targets = document.getElementsByClassName("changable");

const firstEl = targets[0];

if (firstEl) {
  Array.from(targets).slice(1).reduce((prev, el, idx, arr) => {
    prev.addEventListener("transitionend", e => {
      el.style.transform = `scale(${(((idx+1) / arr.length)+1) *2})`;
    });
    return el;
  }, firstEl);

  transformer.addEventListener("click", e => {
    firstEl.style.transform = "scale(2)";
  });
}
```

```css
.changable {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: transform 200ms ease;
}
```

```html
<p><span class="changable">Lorem Ipsum</span> <span class="changable">dolumn deloris</span> <span class="changable">dolumn deloris</span> <span class="changable">dolumn deloris</span> <span class="changable">dolumn deloris</span> <span class="changable">dolumn deloris</span>  <span class="changable">dolumn deloris</span> <span class="changable">dolumn deloris</span> <span class="changable">dolumn deloris</span> <span class="changable">dolumn deloris</span></p>
<button id="transformer" type="button">Transform</button>
```